# Nvidia HDMI audio not visible on system

Tags: arch-linux, audio, nvidia

I recently installed Arch Linux on my pc. I'm using a Nvidia GTX 660 Ti connected to a receiver over HDMI. I can't get audio to work over this HDMI connection. Next to my video card I have an onboard realtek audiochip which I really don't want to disable and a AMD R7 videocard which is disabled in efi.
I'm using the Nvidia proprietary drivers and my wholse system is updated as of today.

`lspci -k` reports:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 841e
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`aplay -l` reports:

```
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
```

how can I get my HDMI port to show up as an audio device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the IOMMU implementation on my chipset. Apparently the combination of the IOMMU and my audiocard didn't work, after disabling the IOMMU in EFI it magically worked.