# How linux-compatible is the Sager NP7950 laptop? (lspci -v?)

Tags: laptop, hardware-compatibility

I am looking for a laptop that I can use for blender on linux and for gaming in windows.  The Sager NP7950 (aka Clevo N950K6?) caught my eye, but I have not been able to find out any information about how well-supported its hardware is by linux drivers.  I know that the Alienware 15 I tried did not even have HDMI audio without PCI tricks ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394725/154635 )

Would someone with this laptop answer with the output of `lspci -v` and the kernel version? (even if it is just from a live DVD).  And if you actually installed Linux on this, please point out any speedbumps you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Using a gentoo live USB stick I was able to collect the following information:

```
livecd ~ # lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 591f (rev 05)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Memory behind bridge: de000000-df0fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
        Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
        Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
        Capabilities: [d94] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5912 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
        Memory at dd000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a2af (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
        Memory at df410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a2b1
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at df42e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a2ba
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at df42d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a282 (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
        Memory at df428000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Memory at df42c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at df42b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a292 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: df300000-df3fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [220] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a294 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
        Memory behind bridge: df200000-df2fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [220] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a296 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: df100000-df1fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [220] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2c4
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a2a1
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: fast devsel
        Memory at df424000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
        Memory at df420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at df400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a2a3
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at df42a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c20 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Capabilities: [900] #19
        Kernel modules: nouveau

02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [68] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [200] #19
        Capabilities: [300] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 851b
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at df215000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
        Expansion ROM at df200000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates

03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Memory at df214000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at df210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 1010
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 90-61-ae-ff-ff-b3-38-ff
        Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
```

and

```
livecd ~ # lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5a7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13fe:3d00 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Chicony might be the webcam.  I speculate the Kingston is an SD card reader.  The 8087:0a2b Intel seems to be the Bluetooth.  Including `lsusb -v` output would exceed the character limit for stackexchange posts.

It appears the wifi card is not supported in the old gentoo image I used for this test.  Once I got gentoo installed and running a recent kernel (4.12.12) I was able to make the wifi work using the `iwlwifi` driver and a recent set of firmware (`emerge linux-firmware`).

Another oddity is that the internal flat panel display is connected to the Intel graphics chip, and all the external ports (HDMI + 2DP) are connected to the nVidia.  I was able to make them all usable using [the Gentoo NVIDIA/Optimus instructions](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA/Optimus) .

Also missing from that lspci output is the PCI device for HDMI audio.  To make it appear, you must use the techniques outlined in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394725/154635 .