# Why is the connected HDMI receiver not detected by PulseAudio?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, pulseaudio, hdmi

After connecting my GTX 980 Ti to my Onkyo TX-NR509 receiver via HDMI I have the following situation:

- `nvidia-settings` lists HDMI-0 as connected and even shows the name of the receiver.
- `pavucontrol` lists GM200 High Definition Audio (so it's not [this common issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393833/3645)) but all the profiles are listed as "unplugged" and "unavailable".
- The receiver says "No Signal".

How do I convince PulseAudio that the receiver is connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable the receiver as a "screen" in `nvidia-settings`:

1. Run `sudo nvidia-settings`
2. Go to X Server Display Configuration
3. Select the receiver
4. Change the configuration to X screen 0
5. Set the position and size to the same as another screen
6. Apply and save the X configuration file